# Accessing a parent class's protected method from outside a child class (with reflection or anything that would work)

Tags: java, testing, reflection, junit, powermock

I've looked around for a solution with no luck, here's what I have and what I'm trying to achieve

**Parent Class**

```
public abstract class MyAbstractParentClass{
     private String privateParentField;

     protected String getPrivateParentField(){
          return privateParentField;
     }

     public void setField(String value){
          privateParentField = value;
     }
}
```

**Child Class**

```
public class MyChlidClass extends MyAbstractParentClass{
     @Override
     public void setField(String value){
          super.setField(value);
     }
}
```

I'm trying to call the `MyChlidClass` 's `setField` method and then call the `MyAbstractParentClass` 's `protected String getPrivateParentField()` afterwords;

```
@Test
public void f(){
    Method[] m = MyChlidClass.class.getDeclaredMethods();
    for (Method method : m) {
        System.out.println(method.getName());
    }
}
```

But this code above returns only declared methods in `MyChlidClass` without the parent class's `protected` ones, how could I access the protected method? any ideas?

thank you very much in advance :)

**EDIT**
Here's the final solution for those interested

```
MyChildClass child = new MyChildClass();
chlid.setField("FOO_BAR");

Method getPrivateParentField = child.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredMethod("getPrivateParentField");
getPrivateParentField.setAccessible(true);

String result = (String) getPrivateParentField.invoke(child);
System.out.println((String)result); //prints out FOO_BAR
```

PS : there are some exceptions you can either catch or add throws declaration for them;

thanks again for your help

Comment: Using `Override` without anything to extend? And why you would like to override the setter method? Is it obviously nothing change from before?

Comment: @Grazenezz : sorry i just forgot to write the extends, and this is just an example (simple enough) to make what i want to achieve clear, thanks for the pointer to the mistake :)

Comment: @K-SaMa whats the package structure like ? please share that info

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the super class methods by calling

```
MyChlidClass.class.getSuperclass().getDeclaredMethods();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can increase the visibility when you extend a class. You don't need to change the code of MyChlidClass, you can just extend it:

```
public class MyGrandChlidClass extends MyChlidClass{

     @Override
     public String getPrivateParentField(){
          return super.getPrivateParentField();
     }
}

@Test
public void f(){
    MyGrandChlidClass myGrandChlidClass = new MyGrandChlidClass();
    myGrandChlidClass.setField("hello");
    System.out.println(myGrandChlidClass.getPrivateParentField());
}
```

Comment: it's obvious it would work that way, but I'm not allowed to change the code;

Comment: @K-SaMa Then, could you extend the child class with another subclass? That way, you are not changing MyAbstractParentClass or MyChlidClass code.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access protected methods directly from outside class. It can only be accessed from within the class or inherited classes. To access this from outside, you will have to create a public method in the child class that calls the protected method of the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Use `getDeclaredMethods()` on the parent class to get information about the parent classes' protected methods.